# FineUploader S3: Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

Spent a day trying to make fine-uploader works according to documentation. Lots of problems in docs and examples.
I've stuck on Forbidden response from Amazon S3.
What I use:

- Fine-uploader 5.4.1
- PHP Endpoint from https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server

Create IAM user in Amazon S3. Attached AmazonS3FullAccess policy to it. 
I've set up keys in PHP endpoint

```
$_ENV['AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY']='OMC0snHLzoqLGToJnn20zrZidx5JLJLI4ksXKhoX';
/*$_ENV['AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY']='';
$_ENV['AWS_SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY']='';*/
$_ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']='mybucketname';
```

Trying to upload file and JS console shows POST request to my endpoint, endpoint returns policy and signature. Then an OPTIONS request sent to mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com. 403 Forbidden in result.
Firefox shows that this OPTIONS request is kind of empty. Nothing on Parameters and Response tabs of Web Console shown (while same tabs are not empty for POST requests to my endpoint). 
Where to dig, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Got it - needed to enable Amazon CORS and use endpoint-cors.php for this

Comment: You do not need to (and should not) use endpoint-cors unless your signature server is also cross origin.